# Highspeed Autocad Infrastructure

Tags: autocad

I have a customer who is looking to implement autocad on their network. Now they want to have a server which houses all the files, which each file can range anywhere from 5GB to 100GB, now i'm not sure what to recommend as far as networking is concerned, i wanted to put in a 3750 and run cat6 through out the office, and each pc including the server will have enterprise ssd drives, does any one have any recommendations with this type of setup or should i even look into running fiber through the office which really looks like overkill for this, but not sure.

Comment: 10GBase-T is a thing now.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing - 10Base-T over a Cisco 93180YC-EX would be cheap and fast.

Comment: Thanks for your response, that might be a little too expensive for them, any possibility to do this via 1GB with cat6? or would that be too slow?

Comment: 1GB is too slow _at home_. And you can get PCI Express 10GBase-T NICs under $100 now. The switch is still going to cost a few bucks though...